# including SDL2 headers causes any program to crash

Tags: c, crash, visual-studio-2019, sdl-2

I'm trying to install SDL2 on Visual Studio 2019 but the following code crashes on start:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: How exactly does it crash on start?

Comment: There is the output of the program : Sortie de D:\Users\PROPRIETAIRE\Documents\5 cours UTT\exoOpenGl\x64\Debug\exoOpenGl.exe (processus 14508) avec le code -1073741701.

Comment: Yes it's works thank you very much